# Why are my 74F chips incompatible with 74LS?

Tags: digital-logic, logic-gates, 74ls161

I have a functioning electronic project I made as a hobby using SN74LS161 4 bit counters and SN74LS08 quad AND gates. I replaced the counters with SN74F161 which are supposed to be faster but have the same logic levels of LS series and yet it doesn't work with the 74LS08 AND gates. Why is that?

Comment: You must be using the same "technology" ... for all devices ... Post schematic, please.

Comment: I know it can cause problems to mix things up. I am just curious to hear other opinions on why it isn't working since i am still a beginner. Looking at the datasheets of the components, they should be interchangeable just fine

Comment: Define "doesn't work" please. What does it do or doesn't do, if it does not do what you expect it to do? How are the chips used? Maybe mounted on a breadboard or something like that, with long jumper wires, and without bypass caps? On paper, they are interchangeable by function and specs, but faster chips need much more from the platform they are used on.

Comment: "F" devices are much faster than "LS" devices. So, behaviors may be "different".

Comment: Speed in itself shouldn't cause issues unless it's a poor design that relies on certain amounts of delay, but faster devices normally use more current and may cause bigger spikes on a poor power supply or less than ideal breadboard. Keep supply wires short and make sure you have plenty of decoupling capacitors.

Comment: Things to keep an eye on include clock signal transition times & glitches.

Comment: 74F is pretty hard to find these days; if you want fast logic with TTL input levels, 74HCT or 74AHCT is going to be easier to get.

Answer (score 8):

> I replaced the counters with SN74F161 which are supposed to be faster but have the same logic levels of LS series and yet it doesn't work with the 74LS08 AND gates. Why is that?

It would be interesting to know in exactly what way it doesn't work. However overall, different behaviour means you have timing or electrical characteristics of your design, probably unintentional, which are sensitive to the differences between 74F and 74LS families.

Just a couple of examples of the relevant differences include:

- The faster rise/fall times (edge rates) of 74F make supply decoupling *noticeably* more critical than with 74LS. You may need to add / improve the location of decoupling capacitors. As pointed out below, proper grounding also becomes more critical.
- Also the different timing (e.g. shorter propagation delays in the 74F family) can make some designs fail, if they rely (perhaps unintentionally) on slower 74LS timing.

Here are a couple of extracts from old [National Semiconductor Application Note 661 "FAST/FASTr Design Considerations"](https://docs.rs-online.com/8be7/0900766b80024d5c.pdf) which discusses how to design with the 74F family (a.k.a. "FAST") and compares them to other TTL families:

> With the advent of FAST/FASTr, with considerably faster edge rates and switching times, proper grounding practice has become of primary concern in printed circuit layout. Poor circuit grounding layout techniques may result in cross-talk and slowed switching rates. This reduces overall circuit
> performance and may necessitate costly redesign. Also when FAST chips are substituted for standard TTL-designed printed circuit boards, faster edge rates can cause noise problems.

> ... simply replacing TTL circuits with FAST/FASTr compatible circuits is not always as easy as it may seem, especially on two-sided boards.

I recommend reading the whole thing as there is lots of interesting info there, even if it isn't all related to your specific issue.

---

Here's a little anecdote from around 40 years ago: I remember the Apple ][ microcomputer having some tight timing requirements in its TTL design. A few parts of the design were so timing sensitive that even 74LS ICs from manufacturer X could not be replaced by the same 74LS part number from manufacturer Y, due to *very slight* timing differences between manufacturers of the *same 74LS part number*.

Comment: +1. I completely agree with you: possibly the problem(s) is due to "critical races" between signals and thing like that.

Comment: Treat 74F, 74AS, 74S, 74AC, 10K/100K ECL ... circuitry like radio circuitry - no matter how slow your clocks are, your edges are in the VHF range and need to be treated as such. Gounding and decoupling matters a lot.